# SOQL Order By with Limit

Tags: soql

I have a question about using **Order By** in my **SOQL**.
My query looks like this

```
Select Id,FirstName,LastName from Contact Order By FirstName Limit 100.
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve I have a search component which on load shows me a drop down with 100 Contacts and when I type ahead it shows me a list of Contacts that matches the criteria i.e Name.This seems to be working fine however when I was checking the Query performance using **Query Plan** in **Developer Console** I noticed the **Cost** is showing a major difference with and without using Order By Clause.For example I noticed the following numbers.

1. Using Order By : Cost Rate = 0.5567
2. Without Order by : Cost Rate = 0.18

Any idea on how to overcome this and by the way I applied filters using  **where** clause I still see this considerable difference.

I have close to 3 Million Contacts in my org.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the cost is below 1, you have little to worry about.

The main way you would increase your selectivity is by adding filters in your `WHERE` clause. Even if there is still a difference between the two, your query will be comfortably selective.

You need to make sure your filters all use indexes. Specifically based on your comments, that [precludes the use of leading wildcards](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/07/maximizing-the-performance-of-force-com-soql-reports-and-list-views.html):

> ## Using Leading % Wildcards
>
> A LIKE condition with a leading % wildcard does not use an index.
>
> ```
> SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE '%Acme%'
> ```

Comment: Yeah although my Cost Rate is below 1 when I started testing this in a org with 3 Million Contacts,on type ahead it errors out

Comment: If you have 3M records, you are going to need to filter on indexed fields. Using `ORDER BY` or not is a very small straw on the camel's back here.

Comment: Sorry My bad forgot to include the filter in my query above.I'm actually using a filter Select Id,FirstName,LastName from Contact where Name Like '%Test%' Order By Name Limit 100.I still see the issue

Comment: @saikirankotha You won't be able to use leading wildcards with this data volume. Maybe it would work with SOSL...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a millions of data, you need to use either Salesforce provided index fields or otherwise request Salesforce for custom index for filtering and filter condition should be selective.

For more info, refer [Improve SOQL Query Performance - Selectivity and Custom Indexes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Checklist-for-Custom-Index-Requests&language=en_US&type=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think most appropriate way to do search with large data is SOSL

```
FIND {searchString} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING CONTACT
```